# insert HTML code in Object Literals attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var circuits_1_=[];
for (var i = 0, len = FeaturesCC.length; i < len; i++) {
var circuit_1_={};
var FeatureCC = FeaturesCC[i];
id_circuit_array.push(FeatureCC.attributes['objectid']);

//var s = '<button id="myDivButton'+i+'">'+FeatureCC.attributes['layer']+'</button>';
//var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
//var t = document.createTextNode(""+FeatureCC.attributes['layer']);
//x.appendChild(t);

circuit_1_={value:i+1, text:""+FeatureCC.attributes['layer']};
circuits_1_.push(circuit_1_);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLsDt.png)

that's my code, I'm trying to make the attribute "text" in the circuits_1 object, a button.
I have tried this

```
circuit_1_={value:i+1, text:"<button id='smth"+i+"' type='button'>"+FeatureCC.attributes['layer']+"</button>"};
```

and that's the result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLdny.png)

I am using this variable as Labels for my chart because I wanna create clickable labels :

```
chartPos_ParCircuit.addAxis("x",{
    labels: circuits_1_,
    }).addAxis("y", { vertical: true, fixLower: "major", fixUpper: "major", includeZero: true }).
      addPlot("default", { type: StackedColumns, gap: 10 });
```

but id didn't work, please HELP me !
PS: I am using DOJO API for charting, If you can suggest me another API where I can make clickable charts and clickable axis please do suggest me !

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2qbtaueo/) is a fiddle of what you posted, with the declaration of `FeaturesCC` and `id_circuit_array`, as well as using the alternate way to define `circuit_1_`. What is not working about that?

Comment: Please check the update of the post

Comment: What charting API are you using Sara?

Comment: What is the error? Could you post FeaturesCC initialization? Perhaps a simple quote in 'layer' attribute breaks the code.

Comment: I am using DOJO API